# How to disabled touch in ExtJs 6

Tags: extjs, touch, touchscreen

Lately, I am testing some functionalities on desktop with touchscreen. I realize the ExtJs code wasn't working right on them because of some ExtJS styles. Can I just disable the touchscreen for the ExtJs framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here what I found: Yes, you can.

There is a way to disable the touch behavior and you should do it before the framework renders its content.

```
//ExtJs 6.0.2
Ext.supports.Touch = false;
Ext.supports.touchScroll = 0;


//ExtJs 6.5.3
Ext.supports.Touch = false;
```

[ExtJs 6.0.2 fiddle example.](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3i8r)

Links related:

- https://forum.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?289792-Turning-off-Touch-support!/page2
- https://forum.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?337169-ExtJS-5-is-broken-in-Firefox-52-when-laptop-has-a-touchscreen/page2
- https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.supports.html
- https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/modern/Ext.supports.html#property-Touch